# gmusicplayer : How to play 1 song repeatedly

Tags: music-player

In **gmusicplayer**, how do you play 1 Specific Song repeatedly?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New LockSong widget to repeat a song was included in V1.1.2

"This option isn't visible in all layout. Apply "list, library & context" layout and take a look just before the current song name : if "lock on current song" is on, you will see a padlock there. If there isn't, "lock" is off."